# How to omit data in dataframe pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to pair opening and closing transactions in a column from each symbol in another column while omitting what I can't pair. All I need to do is omit what I can't pair, but I can't omit that until I can pair things together; no matter how I sort, I will have unnecessary data in my equations.

What you see below is about the fifth different try at this problem.

```
import pandas as pd

with open('TastyTrades.csv', 'r') as trade_history:
    trade_reader = pd.read_csv('TastyTrades.csv')
    options_frame = trade_reader.loc[(trade_reader['Instrument Type'] == 'Equity Option')]
    date_frame = options_frame.sort_values(by=['Symbol', 'Date', 'Action'], ascending=True)
    for date_frame['Symbol'] in date_frame:
        if date_frame['Action'] == ['BUY_TO_OPEN' and 'SELL_TO_CLOSE'] or ['SELL_TO_OPEN' and 'BUY_TO_CLOSE']:
            date_frame.to_csv('new_taste.csv')
```

This results in :

```
ValueError: Lengths must match to compare

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Even further below is an earlier attempt:

```
import pandas as pd

with open('TastyTrades.csv', 'r') as trade_history:
    trade_reader = pd.read_csv('TastyTrades.csv')
    options_frame = trade_reader.loc[(trade_reader['Instrument Type'] == 'Equity Option')]
    date_frame = options_frame.sort_values(by=['Symbol', 'Date', 'Action'], ascending=True)
    close_frame = date_frame[date_frame['Action'].isin(['BUY_TO_OPEN' and 'SELL_TO_CLOSE'] or
                                                       ['SELL_TO_OPEN' and 'BUY_TO_CLOSE'])]

    close_frame.to_csv('new_taste.csv')
```

Which resulted in:

```
,Date,Type,Action,Symbol,Instrument Type,Description,Value,Quantity,Average Price,Commissions,Fees,Multiplier,Underlying Symbol,Expiration Date,Strike Price,Call or Put
75,2020-02-05T09:34:42-0500,Trade,SELL_TO_CLOSE,AA    200320P00013000,Equity Option,Sold 1 AA 03/20/20 Put 13.00 @ 0.12,12,1,12.0,0.0,-0.15,100.0,AA,3/20/2020,13.0,PUT
38,2020-02-12T11:58:10-0500,Trade,SELL_TO_CLOSE,AAL   200320P00023000,Equity Option,Sold 1 AAL 03/20/20 Put 23.00 @ 0.09,9,1,9.0,0.0,-0.15,100.0,AAL,3/20/2020,23.0,PUT
166,2020-01-29T09:41:30-0500,Trade,SELL_TO_CLOSE,AAL   200320P00024000,Equity Option,Sold 1 AAL 03/20/20 Put 24.00 @ 0.48,48,1,48.0,0.0,-0.15,100.0,AAL,3/20/2020,24.0,PUT
216,2020-01-13T15:45:09-0500,Trade,SELL_TO_CLOSE,AAPL  200117C00320000,Equity Option,Sold 1 AAPL 01/17/20 Call 320.00 @ 1.86,186,1,186.0,0.0,-0.15,100.0,AAPL,1/17/2020,320.0,CALL
```

As you can see with this example, it's only grabbing SELL_TO_CLOSE.

Answer (score 0):

To understand what's going on try to interpret your plain Python code `['BUY_TO_OPEN' and 'SELL_TO_CLOSE'] or ['SELL_TO_OPEN' and 'BUY_TO_CLOSE']` which is just equal to `['SELL_TO_CLOSE']`, try to make filters with logical disjunction:

```py
filter1 = date_frame['Action'].isin(['BUY_TO_OPEN', 'SELL_TO_CLOSE'])
filter2 = date_frame['Action'].isin(['SELL_TO_OPEN', 'BUY_TO_CLOSE'])
date_frame[filter1 | filter2]
```

Comment: Now how do I get the strings to print out without the unclosed transactions?
```
date_frame[filter1 | filter2]
```
Has no affect

Comment: So after some more tinkering around, I have come to the conclusion that I still have not omitted the data I am looking to omit.